# Command to Replace Connection Name in IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

Can someone please provide the commands to replace the MQ channel IP and port and  using command line in IBM MQ.

Below Command is not working

```
ALTER CHANNEL('TEC1APP.TO.OCMT') CHLTYPE (SDR) CONNAME('192.168.0.1(1415)') REPLACE
```

Comment: `REPLACE` is a keyword used with a `DEFINE` command not with `ALTER`, if you remove it the command should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change IP to 192.168.0.2 and port number to 1416, below command can be used

```
ALTER CHANNEL('TEC1APP.TO.OCMT') CHLTYPE (SDR) CONNAME('192.168.0.2(1416)')
```